# GPS port closing right after open() command

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port

I'm trying to open a SerialPort, this is the code:

```
if (!gpsPort.IsOpen && ports.Contains(xmNode.InnerText))
{
    gpsPort.Open();
    GPSCOMboBox.SelectedItem = xmNode.InnerText;
}
if (gpsPort.IsOpen)
{
    GPSBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Inside the first if, the port seems to be open, but in the second one it's closed. I think the port closes automatically after opening, but I don't know why. I used the same code for other ports and it worked.

EDIT: The port is open inside the first condition, but closes after it.

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the first condition?  Remove the `&& ports.Contains(xmNode.InnerText)` and see what happens or step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: Yes, I went through it step by step. I enter the first condition and open the port.